# Going back to the previous form many times

Tags: c#, forms, button

I am making a game in c# with many levels and every time you lose, I want to go to a form that gives you many options, including "Retry". 
I know how to acces that form and to reload the level you failed, but I wonder if there's any way I could create that Options form just once and when you click `Retry` to reload the PREVIOUS form each time.

Comment: [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) can you also show code ..there is always a way to do something when it comes to coding

Answer (score 1):

One of the many options you have is to use the [Singleton Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). This is a very quick and overly simplified example, but you would do something like this:

```
public class OptionsForm : Form
{
    private static OptionsForm _instance;
    public static OptionsForm Options
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new OptionsForm();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private int ActualLevel; //variable to hold the level to "go back to/retry"

    public void ShowOptions(int actualLevel)
    {
        ActualLevel = actualLevel;
        //do any processing required
        Show(); // or ShowDialog(); depending on your needs
    }
}
```

You would then do something like this:

```
public void OnLevelFailed() //whatever you call when the user loses the level
{
    OptionsForm.Options.ShowOptions(thisLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into scope of an object in C#, for example by going to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).  The webpage is ancient, but teaches good concepts.

You would basically need to have your options form set up to stay in scope.  One way to do this is to set the object for that form to static.  Then you can reuse it as much as you want.

This adds a lot of complication.  You would have to catch the Form.Closing event, and cancel the close, instead `Hide`ing the form.  When you're done, you may need to manually `Dispose` of the form.

If you only want to do this because it saves the effort of .NET creating the form each time, don't do this.  .NET is very good at creating forms, and doesn't really mind doing so.  The only good reason to do all this is to keep whatever options the user set the same each time the form opens, and there are ways to do this that are considered better coding practice, such as Model View Controllor - the concept is to keep the data (the user's options) separate from the view of the data (the form that displays those options).

Starting out by programming a game is ambitious.  Good luck!